# Как перетаскивать изображения, менять их местами и сохранять (Javascript/PHP)?

Tags: php, javascript, sortable

Есть задача: на веб-странице сделать возможность перестановки фотографий местами с помощью мыши. В результате, порядок изображений должен сохраняться даже после перезагрузки страницы. Сама перестановка происходит без обновления страницы.

В какую сторону копать? И как вообще примерно должно всё происходить?

Comment: Копайте в сторону ajax отправки данных о смене мест картинок на сервер, а на сервере размещайте скрипт, который будет понимать эти данные и перезаписывать их в то место, где у вас хранится информация о положении картинок на странице.

Comment: Порядок сохраняется и един для всех посетителей страницы, или у каждого может быть свой?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для изменения порядка элементов без перезагрузки страницы, посмотрите [Sortable](http://rubaxa.github.io/Sortable/) (без jQuery) или [HTML5 Sortable](http://farhadi.ir/projects/html5sortable/) (с jQuery), или поищите аналоги.

Для сохранения состояния, вам потребуется Javascript`ом делать выборку всех этих элементов и по *AJAX* отправить их идентификаторы на сервер. Затем в цикле сформировать запрос и разом сохранить в базу в том же порядке (используя значение итератора).